# how can I save nested dropdown menu in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

i have a nested dropdowns which are displaying data from database, and i want to get the id of the data when i select it also i want to be able to multiselect but i can't because i can't even get the id that corresponds to that specific data.

am trying to achieve a way users could browse through the data easily and be able to multiselect so far i achieved the browse.

this is model

`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['functional_area','parent_id'];
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Menu', 'id', 'parent_id')->orderBy('sort_order');
    }

    public function children()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id', 'id')->orderBy('sort_order');
    }

    public static function tree()
    {
        return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', '0')->orderBy('sort_order')->get();
    }
}`
```

and this is my controller
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MenuController extends Controller
{
    public function getMenu()
    {
        $menu = new \App\Models\Menu;
        $menuList = $menu->tree();
        return view('index')->with('menulist', $menuList);
    }
   

}
```

`
this is it's index

```
`

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <style>
        .dropdown-menu .nav-item a { color: #000 !important; }
        .dropdown-toggle:after { content: none; }
        .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
        .dropdown-menu li { position: relative }
        .nav-item .submenu { display: none; position: absolute; left: 100%; top: -7px; }
        .dropdown-menu>li:hover { background-color: #f1f1f1; }
        .dropdown-menu>li:hover>.submenu { display: block; }
    </style>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            @each('submenu', $menulist, 'menu', 'empty')

        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', ($event) => $event.stopPropagation());
        if ($(window).width() < 992) {
            $('.dropdown-menu a').click(($event) => {
                $event.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).next('.submenu').length) {
                    $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
                }
                $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', () => $(this).find('.submenu').hide());
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

an it's submenu

```
@if ((count($menu->children) > 0) AND ($menu->parent_id > 0))
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{ $menu->functional_area }}
        @if(count($menu->children) > 0)
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        @endif
    </a>
    @else
<li class="nav-item @if($menu->parent_id === 0 && count($menu->children) > 0) dropdown @endif">
    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{ $menu->functional_area }}
        @if(count($menu->children) > 0)
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        @endif
    </a>
    @endif
    @if (count($menu->children) > 0)
    <ul class="@if($menu->parent_id !== 0 && (count($menu->children) > 0)) submenu @endif dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownBtn">
        @foreach($menu->children as $menu)
        @include('submenu', $menu)
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

hopefully if anyone would help me out.

Comment: You can use a single table with parent_id column (nullable). If the parent_id is null it's a parent menu item. If there is parent_id it's a child item.

Comment: already done it, my question is how to save in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help with your code. But I can show you how I have done category- subcategory select box.  My category Model :

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id',
        'category_name',
        'description',
        'image',
        'slug',
        'status',
    ];

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');

    }  

}
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->orderby('category_name', 'asc')->get();
    return view('dashboards.admins.category.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

Views: create.blade.php

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @php $dashes = ' -- ' @endphp
                                <label>Select parent category*</label>
                                <select type="text" name="parent_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="0">None</option>
                                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>                                         
                                        @php $newDashes = $dashes . ' -- ' @endphp                                            
                                        @foreach ($category->children as $sub)                                              
                                          @include('/dashboards/admins/category/subcategories', ['cat' => $sub, 'dashes' => $newDashes,'parent_id' => ''] )
                                        @endforeach                                       
                                    
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

And partial view to be included in creae.blade - named - subcategories.blade

```
    <option value="{{ $cat->id }}" @if($cat->id == $parent_id) " selected "   @endif >{{ $dashes }}{{  $cat->category_name}}</option>
    @php $newDashes = $dashes. ' -- ' @endphp
    @foreach ($cat->children as $sub)
      @include('/dashboards/admins/category/subcategories', ['cat' => $sub, 'dashes' => $newDashes])
    @endforeach
```

The subcategories are displayed with -- in front of category name and directly under the main category.

Comment: i am displaying and saving it just fine using codes which are similar to yours but now i have a problem with the way datas are saved it's not starting a new field for array values but instead it's keeping them in one field like this ["4","7","9","12","18","19","20"] but i want those to have like their own fields.

Comment: Multiselect will return data in array only.